# How use get Instance function on dataset and filter datatype based data

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to understand about get Instance function on dataset. i have some dataset and i want to map each column based on there datatype(Like int,String and Date) if any wrong type received in dataset then i want to filter that row.

I have Input dataset and there type is (Int, String, String, Date )

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
case class Test(ID:Int,AirName:String,Place:String,TakeoffDate:String)
val df= myFile.map(x => x.split(",") ).map( x=> Test(x(0).toInt,x(1),x(2),x(3)) ).toDF()

+-----+-------+-----+-----------+
|   ID|AirName|Place|TakeoffDate|
+-----+-------+-----+-----------+
|    1|  Delta|  Aus|    1/11/18|
|    2|  Delta|     |    10/5/19|
|Three|   null|  New| 15/10/2018|
|    4| JetAir|  Aus|    11/6/15|
+-----+-------+-----+-----------+
 After Creation of dataset Expected Output Dataset1
+-----+-------+-----+-----------+
|   ID|AirName|Place|TakeoffDate|
+-----+-------+-----+-----------+
|    1|  Delta|  Aus|    1/11/18|
|    2|  Delta|     |    10/5/19|
|    4| JetAir|  Aus|    11/6/15|
+-----+-------+-----+-----------+


Dataset2
+-----+-------+-----+-----------+
|   ID|AirName|Place|TakeoffDate|
+-----+-------+-----+-----------+
|Three|   null|  New| 15/10/2018|
|    4| JetAir|  Aus|    11/6/15|
+-----+-------+-----+-----------+
```

Comment: Have you looked into the `filter` function?

Comment: @Yuval I am new in scala my requirement is to filter data using mapper function (while mapping data). I am trying to check the datatype, if datatype doesn't match than record should go into error file.

Comment: `map` is for when you want to do transformations on the elements. `filter`, which has the type signature of `A => Boolean`, meaning give me an element of any type A, and I'll return a boolean, is for when you want to filter out elements from the `DataStream`. In your case, `A` would be `Test`, and you can use `if-else` expressions to evaluate if it's contents are valid.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I understood your point but is there any parse method which i can apply and map each column with respective datatype if datatype not match i can filter it out.

Comment: Before you turn into a dataframe, filter the elements out i.e. `myFile.map(...).filter(...).toDF`

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov can you please provide me sample syntax for same.